# Typing with keyboard in TimePicker requires pressing "Enter" before "OK", otherwise values discarded

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-timepicker, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-number-picker

My program shows classic `android.app.TimePickerDialog` and listens to `OnTimeSetListener.onTimeSet()` . After migrating from Android 4.3 to 5.1 I noticed that typing minutes using keyboard and pressing "OK" results wrong values passed to `onTimeSet()` handler. However, if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on keyboard before pressing OK button in the dialog (or click on the hours input or just use the spinner), the values are correct.

I think it has something to do with `NumberPicker` focus not cleared, when user presses OK.

It is inconvenient to use the spinner for minutes or additionally press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on keyboard. How to get my values accepted with OK button alone?

```
import android.app.*;
...

private final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        ...
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case TIMEPICKER_DIALOG:
        return new TimePickerDialog(ChannelActivity.this, mTimeSetListener, day.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), day.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
    }
    return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

5 years later I've got this issue.
After hours of search and try, it seems that calling timePicker.clearFocus() will update the NumberPicker which is used internally by the TimePicker

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone bumps into this one (like me)

You need to clear focus on the time picker and read from its object instead of the method args, like this:

```
        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(
            this,
            android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog,
            (timePicker, hr, min) -> {
                timePicker.clearFocus(); // this is must
                textViewHr.setText(String.valueOf(timePicker.getHour())); //read from the view 
                textViewMin.setText(String.valueOf(timePicker.getMinute())); //read from the view 
            },
            hour, //initial hour value
            minute, //initial minute value
            true //is 24 hours format
         );
```